# create table in latex inside table

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


  \begin{center}
       \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
       \hline
        Type of Variation & C& B\\
    \hline \hline
          SNP & 
            \begin{center}
          \begin{tabular}[t]{cccc}
          \centering
          1&2&3&4\\ A&C&G&T\\ A&T&G&T 
          \end{tabular} 
                     \end{center}\\ &&
         \begin{center}
                 \begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
          POS & REF & ALT\\ 
          2 & C & T \\ 
          \end{tabular}
               \end{center}\\ \hline
          \end{tabular}
          \end{center}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the following may be what you're looking for. Observe that all `center` environments have been removed, a single `\centering` instruction is provided immediately ahead of the outermost `tabular` environment, the missing `\begin{table}` instruction is provided, and the number of columns in the outer `tabular` environment is reduced from 4 to 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slightly more open "look"
\centering
\caption{Nested \texttt{tabular} environments}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Type of Variation & C & B \\
\hline \hline
      SNP & 
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}cccc@{}} % "@{}" omits side padding
         1&2&3&4 \\ 
         A&C&G&T \\ 
         A&T&G&T \\
      \end{tabular} &
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ccc@{}}
         POS & REF & ALT\\ 
         2   & C   & T  \\ 
      \end{tabular} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```